# OpenEJBRuntimeException: No port address registry in cucumber java test

Tags: java, cucumber-java, openejb

When I launch cucumber test I get this error :

> org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: No port address registry, it generally means you either didn't activate cxf or don't use tomee+

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add openejb-cxf to your classpath to enable your JAXWS code. Alternatively and if you can, configure openejb to not scan your JAXWS code.

Romain

Comment: Thank you Romain, do you know please how to configure openejb in order to not scan jaxws code ?

Comment: You can add it in the system property openejb.additional.exclude (a csv list of jar name prefixes)